# Django outputting data in templates after .select_related()

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have MySQL DB:

> [image: ERR]

In Django models:

```
class Record(models.Model):
    schema_id  = models.IntegerField()
    project_id = models.IntegerField()
    name       = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Value(models.Model):
    record    = models.ForeignKey(Record)
    key       = models.ForeignKey(Key)
    value     = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Key(models.Model):
    name   = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    encode = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
```

In outputting it should looks like this:

```
## record.name ##
    key.name - value.value 
    key.name - value.value  
    ...

## record.name ##
    key.name - value.value 
    key.name - value.value 
    ...
```

I try to do it using the following code, but it's makes too many queries to database.

```
#in view
records = Record.objects.filter(project_id=1)

#in template
{% for record in records %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="legend">Record:</td>
            <td>{{ record.name }}</td>
        </tr>

        {% for value in record.value_set.all %}
            <tr>
                <td class="legend">{{ value.key.name }}:</td>
                <td>{{ value.value }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endfor %}
```

Using .select_related() i get all data in 2 query, but how iterate this data in templates to get similar structure?

```
records = Record.objects.filter(project_id=1)
values = Value.objects.filter(record__in=records).select_related().order_by('record')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice job for [{% regroup %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) tag.